# sqlQuery using a variable constraint not working.

Tags: r, rodbc

I am trying to pass a query to Access using the RODBC package within R. I can import entire tables using sqlFetch, but I am looking to cherry pick data using a query.

However, I would like to use an R variable to select one of the constraints (Shaft_ID).

To construct the SQL query, I have used both Cat and Paste so I can use quotation marks around the Shaft variable.

My code is as follows:

```
    Shaft<- "S001"
BL <- sqlQuery(myDBcon, paste("SELECT * FROM BL_FGSL WHERE Shaft_ID ='",Shaft,"'"), error = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

This creates a data frame, but it does not find any values. If I replace the variable directly with "S001" it works!

Any ideas chaps?

Comment: I don't think you should use `cat` there. Just omit it.

Comment: `cat` is only used for the side effect of writing to STDOUT (or a file); it returns `NULL` rather than the printed text -- `is.null(cat(1:5, "\n"))`.

Comment: The reason you return nothing is you query is looking for `' S001 '` (with spaces on both sides) because you used `paste()` without specifying the separator: Either use `paste(<SQL string>, sep="")` or `paste0(<SQL String>)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks Partait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL uses the single quote character `'`, but matching up quotes in SQL injection can be irritating and isn't highly recommended.

I would recommend parameterizing your query, and letting the computer do the work of managing your quotes for you.

```
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)

Shaft<- "S001"

BL <- 
  sqlExecute(myDBcon, 
             query = "SELECT * FROM BL_FGSL WHERE Valid = TRUE AND Shaft_ID = ?", 
             data = list(Shaft_ID = Shaft),
             fetch = TRUE, 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
             error = TRUE)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html

Comment: Thanks for that Benjamin, and letting me know that RODBCext exists! I tried the code, but I am getting the following errors:-

Error in sqlExecute(myDBcon, query = "SELECT * FROM BL_FGSL WHERE Valid = TRUE AND Shaft_ID = ?",  : 
  HY104 98 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid precision value 
[RODBCext] Error: SQLBindParameter failed
In addition: Warning message:
HY104 98 [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Invalid precision value

Comment: Is this an issue with matching data types?

Comment: It seems like it.  What is the data type for `Shaft_ID`?

Comment: this might be relevant... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/73ce581e-7e4d-4a41-99be-e3ebafc98402/dataset-using-odbc-giving-error-hy104-invalid-precision-value?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: Shaft_ID has a Short Text data type.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what the issue is. :(